# try to create multi-files Add-on, install fail with Error: module 'bpy' has no attribute 'props'

Tags: python

I have created an addon written in multiple files.

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(operator_add)
else:
    from . import operator_add
    from . import operator_create


import bpy
import bmesh
import os
from operator_add import OBJECT_add
```

I got error message when trying to activate the add-on

`AttributeError: module 'bpy' has no attribute 'props'`

in the operator_add.py I have the class as follow:

```
class OBJECT_add(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myops.addthings"
    bl_label = "Add Base Mesh"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    bl_description ="Add Base Mesh"
    #the error comes from this line:
    objectsToAdd = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    #this is trying to get the property from the UI draw() in the __init__.py

    def execute(self, context):
        add_myobject(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Add `print(bpy.__file__)` to see if the `bpy` module is actually loaded from where you expect.

Comment: What is blender vesrion do you using? Have you read this https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.props.html?highlight=props

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/JacquesLucke/code_autocomplete

Here is a blender add-on that lets you create multi-file add-ons in blender easily. Just download the repository .zip and install the add-on. Next enable it. Now in the text editor click `view > properties` You will now see a couple new panels one named `Addon Development` then you will see a text box. Simply type in the name of your new add-on and click the button that pops up that says `new addon multi-file` Once this is done it will create a multi-file add-on automatically for you. Remember to click `save all files`often and also when you load blender back up and want to work on your add-on again just click the eyedrop tool and you will see a list of all the add-ons you are currently working on and click the one to load and it will. Hope this helps :)

Also in operator_add.py do you have `import bpy`? Maybe thats the reason?

Comment: Exactly what I searched for... last summer. But I will try it out for my addon :-) thanks